# Remove text after some stringin Powershell

Tags: powershell, text

I'm find a lot examples of file splitting by comma, and other character. 
But my target is to get clean xml file without digital signature on it.

Structure of "dirty" xml file is next (Error tag optional) signature can be on one string or two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<File "Some txt">
<Doc "Some txt" />
<Error "Some txt" />
</File>

 o000000ЯђeHђрь Ly]°Еоyн.‚а9Ут8$&Ъё• эИoтхњСђ7Мф YЁ7¤GПaм—1z©°QЩяк002094100901ЇьбSќ–ЏXMLд
```

As you can guess i need next code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<File "Some txt">
<Doc "Some txt" />
</File>
```

I'm trying next script :

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\TEST -Filter S*.xml |  ForEach-Object -Process {
 $filename = $_.FullName
 Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'o000000'} | Set-Content ($filename+".tmp") 
 Remove-Item $filename
 Rename-Item ($filename+".tmp") $filename
  }
```

It can delete signature within one string, but can't delete line breaker after tag, and can't delete second signature string. What can i do?

**================================================================================**
Solution for PowerShell v 2.0 is ( thanks for **@Keith Hill** ):

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\TEST -Filter S*.xml |  ForEach-Object -Process {
    $filename = $_.FullName
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String
    $content -replace '(?ism)(.*?)\s+o000000.*$','$1' | Set-Content "${filename}.tmp"
    Remove-Item $filename
    Rename-Item ($filename+".tmp") $filename
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - read the file as a string then your regex can span lines:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\TEST -Filter S*.xml |  ForEach-Object -Process {
    $filename = $_.FullName
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw
    $content -replace '(?ism)(.*?)\s+o000000.*$','$1' | Set-Content "${filename}.tmp"
    Remove-Item $filename
    Rename-Item ($filename+".tmp") $filename
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but not working fot this case:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<File "Some txt">
<Doc "Some txt" />
<Error "Some txt" />
</File>
 o000000ЛЌ”gЋУ¬xq{ёй#Йш*Ve‹ю—
|1|а1#\b Б©&уь“ѓ3кґ‘бь‰ЗяѓWA¶ыOХЏ‰б–ё002094100901SгSќ–ЏXMLд`

Comment: Script removing only one sign string `o000000ЛЌ”gЋУ¬xq{ёй#Йш*Ve‹ю—`. 
This one `|1|а1#\b Б©&уь“ѓ3кґ‘бь‰ЗяѓWA¶ыOХЏ‰б–ё002094100901SгSќ–ЏXMLд`   still appear on it's place ((

Comment: Sorry, was missing the `-Raw` parameter on Get-Content.  That causes the file to be read as a single string.

Comment: OMG! i have a problem script on target host with win XP isn't working because of parameter -Raw isn't available on PS v.2 ((( what can i dO?

Comment: i'm found a solution for PS v2.0 `$content = Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String`